# Dual booting windows and ubuntu - games

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, games

I have a specific question regarding gaming while dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu. I want to have both operating systems on seperate drives but I'm not really sure how this will impact the games that I have. I recently bought a second SSD to use it only for games. Now I would want to try out dual booting and install Linux on that drive. How would this work? After formatting and installing, can I just put the games as they were and play them while in Windows or do they have to be on the C drive? On the other hand, Linux gaming is also something that I want to take a look at. If I understand correctly, those would be the Linux versions of them? Is it possible to have both Windows and Linux versions installed on the same drive? Thats's essentially my question. Sorry if it's dumb but I couldn't really find a clear answer elsewhere.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can put Windows with Windows games on first SSD and Linux with Linux games on second SSD.

You can also keep Windows 10 on first SSD and make logical drives on second SSD  - put Windows games on one logical drive and Linux system on second logical drive of that second SSD. It makes sense in a way because Windows 10 can be pretty disk demanding.

Linux games have to be on Linux file system, but you can have them on same physical disk as explained in second paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it out. I wouldn't even bother to ask that question if not for the fact that I have pretty much ran out of space on my Windows drive. I thought that having both the games and linux installation on the same drive would be pretty neat but I just wasn't sure about game installs. Now I know a method. Thanks again!